# how to get message back to Forms PCL from Android Prj?

Tags: xamarin

how i can change label value in my content page and its value coming from android activity.

How can I do this?
I don't think I need a custom render since I just want to use normal forms label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **MessagingCenter.** check below url

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26681/need-to-get-message-back-to-forms-pcl-from-android-prj